# How to assign a unique color for each pixel in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to assign a unique color for each pixel in the image by Python.

The following image is what I want to get.

[image]

I think the color may be calculated by the location of the pixel.

I have tried the following method, but the color of the pixel in the same row seems identity.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(0,1,255*255).reshape(255,255)
color_map = np.stack([a,a,a],axis=0)
color_map = np.transpose(color_map, (1,2,0))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(color_map , cmap = "brg")
```

[image]

Comment: you could use all permutations of (0-255,0-255,0-255) in the RGB channels.instead of the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something like this after this implementation. Try to fiddle with the value of m and you will see different results.

```
m = 256
img = np.zeros((m,m,3), dtype=np.uint8)
R, G, B = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]
R_flat = R.flatten()
G_flat = G.flatten()
B_flat = B.flatten()

c = 0
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        for k in range(256):
            if c == len(R_flat):
                break
            R_flat[c] = i
            G_flat[c] = j
            B_flat[c] = k
            c += 1
        
img[:,:,0] = R_flat.reshape((m,m))
img[:,:,1] = G_flat.reshape((m,m))
img[:,:,2] = B_flat.reshape((m,m))


plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

**Result :**

It works best for m = 256:

[image: m = 256]

Looks interesting for m = 220:

[image: m = 220]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by the following code inspired by @Mohammed Aadil.

```py
a = np.linspace(0,255, 256).astype(np.uint8)
xx,yy =np.meshgrid(a,a)
ans = np.stack([xx,yy, yy], axis=0)
ans = np.transpose(ans, (1,2,0))
plt.imshow(ans)
```

[image]